# How to close browser after download

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am opening a webpage that automatically downloads a data file.

This works but I am forced to close the new browser manually as it gets stuck on line shown below.

No profile options appears to help this.

```
import lzma
import struct
import pandas as pd

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

def download():
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
    profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", True)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", False)
    #profile.set_preference("browser.download.alwaysOpenPanel", False)

    profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", r'C:\Users\HistDataTick')
    profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/zip,text/plain,text/csv,application/csv,application/download,application/octet-stream")

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Downloads\geckodriver-v0.30.0-win64/geckodriver.exe',
                               firefox_profile=profile)

    s = 'https://datafeed.dukascopy.com/datafeed/NZDUSD/2022/03/12/BID_candles_min_1.bi5'

    driver.get(s)  #<<<< GETS STUCK HERE
    # #time.sleep(3)
    # button = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'file_down')  #find_element_by_id('file_down')
    # button.submit()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()


t = download()
```

Comment: You actually do not need Selenium and browser to download this file with python

Comment: not sure it's stuck there... but there will be no DOM if it only triggers a download.  This means that the only thing you can do with the driver is perform another .get().  If it is waiting for a page load timeout, then it'll take a while... maybe that's what's happening.  You could set the PageLoadStrategy so that it does not wait for a DOM load:  https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/options/#pageloadstrategy